# Animate series of images of unknown array size

Tags: ios, uiimageview, ios-animations

I a fetching from the network **X** images, and want to display them using animations. I have a simple UIImageView which I wants to display each image for 5 seconds, and then proceed to the next one. If reached to the end, then it will repeat again forever.

I want to use animation **TransitionFlipFromLeft**.
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You can use iCaraousal for the same effect. It is good one

Comment: And what have you tried? What have you already looked into? Did you look at `NSTimer` class? Where does your solution fail? Post some code :)

Comment: Wow! you just said NSTimer, and in 5 minutes I got the solution! Thanks!